# Trying to load up my .html pages I created on Sublime on Mac OS, on a windows and all that's showing are symbols?

Tags: html, css

I have been creating my own website using Sublime on a MAC OS. I saved all of my files to my USB stick but a windows OS at the university could not open my page, all that was coming up were weird symbols.

[The first image is opening the file in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JrUM.jpg)

[The second image is opening it in I.Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8aNg.png)

Comment: Please post an example, I don't know what "weird symbols" means.

Comment: Are all the same files there on the USB? Is it possible this is a file system difference due to the way the USB drive was formatted? There shouldn't really be an issue in saving a html file on a Mac and then viewing it on a Windows machine.

Comment: From past experience it sounds as it you have been saving from the app directly to the USB stick, which is perhaps formatted as FAT32 or something other than Mac OS Extended, and it has corrupted the files.  Your site files however have a .html or .htm extension, try opening them in a plain text editor (not word) and see if you can see the content.

Comment: Just posted two links inside my question with a clear image of what shows up when trying to open my file on a Windows OS in Chrome and Internet Explorer. Any help what so ever would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have opened `._Index.html` rather than `Index.html` (you can see this in the URL bar). The former is not the page that you have created, but a metadata file created by the Mac OS. You need to open `Index.html` instead.

On a UNIX system like the Mac OS, files beginning with a dot `.` are hidden from view by default, so you might not ever have seen the metadata file. This is not the case on Windows.

I'm no expert in this matter, but it looks like the metadata file contains information on tags that you've added to the file in the Finder. I believe that this information is generally stored in the filesystem metadata rather than as a separate hidden file. However, your portable drive is probably formatted as FAT32, which doesn't support that kind of metadata. I suppose that the hidden metadata file is a sort of hack to store the metadata on filesystems that don't natively support it.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are right for some reason there is another file for each of my .html with all the meta data in. Thank you so much for your answer, makes sense to me now and I no longer have to worry all of my work is lost for my uni project.